# Highlight Rows from find Method in Powerbuilder Datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am new to powerbuilder. I tried creating a datawindow and fetch some details. I put a button to find rows that satisfies a specific expression and it works good. Now i need to highlight the result set of rows from the find method. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

So...you are showing a set of rows and then finding a subset within them?  If so you need to use the find method to find a row, set the select row indicator, find the next one, set its indicator, and so on.

Comment: Hi .. i didnt get you. while giving a find event, in the row we will be getting the total count. then how to highlight those whole rows.

Comment: My code is :long ll_num
int li_count

for li_count=1 to dw_1.rowcount() 
ll_num=dw_1.find (" user_id < 10",li_count,dw_1.rowcount())
dw_1.setrow(ll_num)
next ... will this highlight all rows with user id less than 10

Comment: Got Answer. Thanks for helping